# Docker-compose: how to do version 2 "mem_limit" in version 3?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Recently, I tried upgrading a version `2` `docker-compose` `yaml` file to version `3`.  Specifically, I was going from 2.1 to 3.4.  Using `docker-compose` version 1.18.0 and `docker` version 18.06.01.

The first attempt caused `docker-compose` to abort because of the presence of the Version 2 option: `mem_limit`.  Reading these [Version 3 docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning), it clearly states `mem_limit` was removed and to see "upgrading" to guide usage away from this option.   These instruction tell you to use the `deploy` section with `resources`.  Making these changes to the `docker-compose.yml` file and the system started normally.

Unfortunately, I missed the disclaimer in there where it states that `deploy` is ignored by `docker-compose`!  My question: is there a way to use Compose file reference 3 and `docker-compose` while still enforcing a container memory limit?

Comment: they are quite clear on that: v3 is  meant for Swarm and Kubernete. You cannot restrict memory using v3 and not Swarm and should keep to v2.

Read this thread for more.
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4513

Comment: Having finally gone through enough of the documents, yes it is in there, though I totally agree with the selected answer below - it is hardly "quite clear"!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is not.

> Between versions 2.x and 3.x...several options have been removed
>
> ...`mem_limit`, `memswap_limit`: These have been replaced by the resources key under deploy. deploy configuration only takes effect when using docker stack deploy, and is ignored by docker-compose.
> See [Compose: Upgrading from 2 to 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-2x-to-3x)

And also you don't have to upgrade, you don't even have any reason to upgrade if you don't use swarm.

Sadly in the official docker docs, there is stated

> Version 3 (most current, and recommended)

which isn't actually really true, if you use docker-compose without swarm, there is hardly any reason to switch or to use on new project v3. In the official repository you can see comments like this [[2](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4513#issuecomment-281478365)][[3](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5586#issuecomment-375577458)].
Also in the [compatibility-matrix](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#compatibility-matrix) you can see that v2 is still upgraded even when v3 is out for quite some time. And only v1 is marked as deprecated.

Comment: Thank you - while I don't like the answer I suspected, but did not know this to be the case.  Unfortunately, I believe that "start_period" (new option under 'healthcheck') is only support in V3 and I really wanted to use that, but not at the cost of losing memory limits!

Comment: Adding to my previous comment - if I were to use version 2.3 or later with compose, then the option I want, start_period, is available.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example Docker Compose file version 3.8 with memory limitations:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 256M
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: myapp-data
        target: /var/www/html
    networks:
      - myapp-net
    environment:
      - NGINX_HOST=example.com
      - NGINX_PORT=80

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 512M
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: myapp-db
        target: /var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - myapp-net
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=myapp

volumes:
  myapp-data:
  myapp-db:

networks:
  myapp-net:
```