# What is difference between extends and anchor tag (<<: *anchor) in yaml (Gitlab CICD)?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

When we use extends and when we use anchor tag ?
Please refer below CI CD pipeline

```
  stages:
    - stage1
  .random-variables:
    variables:
      ABC: ${XYZ}
    
  .hidden-job: &hidden-job
    stage: stage1
    image: docker:latest
    services:
      - docker:dind
    script:
      #  My Scripts

  hidden-job:dev:
    extends:
      - .random-variables
    <<: *hidden-job
    only:
      - dev
```

Thanks in advance for clarifying my doubt.

As of now I understand how pipeline is working like anchor tag is use with <<: *alias to pull in the other block of code in current block.

Same extends is use to pull in variables in current block

Comment: One (anchors) is basic YAML syntax, the other (extends) is a specific feature of how GitLab interprets your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are essentially the same except you can use a yaml anchor from another file using the `extends` field. For example:

```
include:
 - 'https://example.com/some-file.yaml'

# this will work
my_job:
  extends: .some-anchor-from-the-included-file

# this will fail
my_other_job:
  <<: *some-anchor-from-the-included-file
```

You can also use the `!reference` tag to pull yaml anchors from other files.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags

Answer (score 4):

One more piece of information could be the deep merge behaviour of the extends keyword.

Example based on this resolved issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/36372#note_706349820

```
.base:
  variables:
    VAR1: hello
  script: exit 0

job:
  extends: .base
  variables:
    VAR2: mello


#THE RESULT IS:
job:
  variables:
    VAR1: hello
    VAR2: mello
  script: exit 0
```

Please correct me if I am wrong since I didn't tested it personally, but based on my comprehension, with anchors, you would have this behaviour:

```
.base: &base
  variables:
    VAR1: hello
  script: exit 0

job:
  <<: *base
  variables:
    VAR2: mello


#THE RESULT IS:
job:
  variables:
    VAR2: mello
  script: exit 0
```

This post makes me confident in what I just write above:
[Merging Yaml arrarys nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965417/merging-yaml-arrarys-nested)

Comment: I just checked it, you are right! In this case `extends` keeps both variables and the yaml anchor overwrites the `variables` field as there is only one element.

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Mav3656's correct answer:

If you try something like this:

```
.base: &base
  variables:
    VAR1: hello
    VAR2: TEST

job:
  extends: .base
  variables:
    VAR1: MELLO1
  script:
    - echo "{$VAR1}, {$VAR2}"

job2:
  <<: *base
  variables:
    VAR1: MELLO2
  script:
    - echo "{$VAR1}, {$VAR2}"
```

the first job will print `{MELLO1}, {TEST}` whereas the second job with the yaml anchor overwrites the whole `variables` field resulting in `{MELLO2}, {}`, discarding `VAR2`.

This is shows the differences in the merging strategies of yaml anchors and the `extends` keyword. The difference does NOT only lie in the fact that `extends` can be used across different files. The accepted answer is definitely lacking this!

And by the way: changing the values of a job that is imported and has been used via yaml anchors will not change anything. Yaml anchors are resolved on the file level:

File1:

```
include:
  - "/CICD/test.gitlab-ci.yml"

.wohoo:
  variables:
    VAR: "OVERWRITTEN"
```

File2:

```
.wohoo: &yaml
  variables:
    VAR: "HIDDEN"
  script:
    - echo "running template job {$VAR}"

job1:
  <<: *yaml
  variables:
    VAR: "VISIBLE"
```

In this case the configurations from File1 will be ignored, `$VAR` will carry the value `VISIBLE`. If you `extends` instead of yaml anchors in File2 instead:

File2_NEW:

```
.wohoo:
  variables:
    VAR: "HIDDEN"
  script:
    - echo "running template job {$VAR}"

job1:
  extends: .wohoo
  variables:
    VAR: "VISIBLE"
```

Your job1 would be overwritten and the variable would be `OVERWRITTEN`.